# Need to count certain text in Excel relative to today's date with large amounts of variable data in each cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

I have exported updates from my help desk ticket tracking software into Excel. Each cell contains all updates made on a single ticket over the life of the ticket. Here is an example of a typical cell:

`IM1234567;"4/20/16 15:31:01 US/Eastern (Smith John ABC DEF GHI): Some text about the status of the ticket. 04/13/16 23:53:06 (Doe Jane ABC DEF GHI): Some more text about the status."`

The goal is to count each technician's name in the ticket if they have made an update to the ticket in the last month. I have all the technicians broken out into individual columns with each ticket in its own row. Here is an example:

```
Ticket     Jane Doe     John Smith    James Adam    Etc
IM1234567    1              0             0           0
IM1234568    0              1             0           0
IM1234569    0              0             1           0
```

Given how varied each ticket is I am not sure how to go about doing this. Some of the tickets are extremely long, and as they are free text fields punctuation and spelling are sometimes lacking.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Are the names always prefixed by `(` , and are they always in the format `lastname firstname` ?

Comment: Will they always be in _surname firstname_ format?

Comment: @Olly Yes, for the most part they are lastname firstname. There is a small amount that have usernames instead, but it is not enough to cause an issue from what I can tell. Also, yes the names are always prefixed by    (

Comment: Why won't the ones that have just a single username cause an issue?  How do you expect to extract those from your freeform data?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld My plan was to get the standard names counted and then add columns for the usernames and add those names to the full name column they belong to.

Comment: Will the first row of your output table (with the names) be pre-populated?  Or does it have to be generated from the list of tickets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated to handle 1- or 2-digit month and day.

**EDIT2**: Updated to automatically calculate how far ahead in the ticket to look for the name.

If you're ok with the name in the table being in last first format, this will work. Enter as an array formula (`ctrl`+`shift`+`enter`):

```
SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))),1))),IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2)))-1,1))),0,IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))),8),"/",""))=6,IF(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))),8)),IFERROR(DATEVALUE(MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))),7)),IFERROR(DATEVALUE(MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))),6)),0)))>EDATE(TODAY(),-3),IF(IFERROR(FIND(" ("&C$1,MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))),SEARCH(")",MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2)))+8,LEN($A2))))),0)>0,1,0),0),0)),0))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked splendidly. Thank you so much! I did try to adjust the 30 to get more, I tried 90, and it stopped working, just returned a 0 when I set the date to say 04/05/18.

Comment: @Tydis I got tripped up on the date formatting. The previous answer wouldn't handle date formatting with both a 1-digit day and month (e.g., 7/7/18). The updated answer should.

Comment: Another update. `DATEVALUE' was giving some unanticipated behavior when dealing with spaces. Added a check for expected formatting.

Comment: So I am now able to change the number from 30+LEN to say 120+LEN and as long as the date is within 30 days it counts the entry correctly, but as soon as I change the entry date of the update to say 04/05/18, it ceases to be counted. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When the formula finds a date, the "30" tells the `FIND` function how far ahead (in characters) to search in the ticket to find the name in row 1 of the current column. If you want to adjust the date range, you need to edit the `EDATE(TODAY(),-1)` portion of the formula. The "-1" tells it how many months to look ahead (-1 means 1 month back). So if you wanted to look back, say 4 months, you would use `EDATE(TODAY(),-4)`.

Comment: Ok. One more update to automatically calculate how far ahead in the string to look. It will look up until the next ")".

Answer (score 0):

The formula `=(LEN(<Insert Complete string ticket address here>)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(<Insert Complete string ticket address here>,<Insert name or address here>,"")))/LEN(<Insert name or address here>)` should do the trick.

Edit: To solve the `lastname`, `firstname` order issue, flip the names when you refer to them in your formula with: `=MID(B1&" "&B1,FIND(" ",B1)+1,LEN(B1))`.

So, in resume, place on `B2`:

`=(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,MID(B$1&" "&B$1,FIND(" ",B$1)+1,LEN(B$1)),"")))/LEN(MID(B$1&" "&B$1,FIND(" ",B$1)+1,LEN(B$1)))` and drag it to the other cells.

Finally, for find the value you want (sorry for the late edit, I didn't read your question with much attention), try the following (on `B2` cell):

`{=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(TEXT(NOW()-31;"m/yy");(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A2; "."; "</s><s>") & "</s></t>"; "//s")));0)<>0;LEN((FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A2; "."; "</s><s>") & "</s></t>"; "//s")))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE((FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A2; "."; "</s><s>") & "</s></t>"; "//s"));MID(B$1&" "&B$1;FIND(" ";B$1)+1;LEN(B$1));"")))/LEN(MID(B$1&" "&B$1;FIND(" ";B$1)+1;LEN(B$1))))}`

Please make sure:
First: you place the formula as an array (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) to enter the brackets;
Second: check the format display `"m/yy"` used in your country or in your Excel version.

I tested the formula on a similar file of my own and it worked.

Comment: So like this `=(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B1,"")))/LEN(B1)`?

Comment: Right.. Assuming in `A2` you have the complete ticket string.

Comment: So that will work for counting all the entries, but how do I factor in for entries only made in the last month?

Comment: It does not appear Excel 2010 has the FILTERXML function, or am I not doing something correctly?

Comment: Did you evaluate the formula? What's the value/error you see?

Comment: It is giving me an error on the -31 after NOW(). It simply says "The formula you typed contains an error" and highlights the -31.

Comment: It highlights just the `-31`? Or `-31;"m`? Do you use `,` or `;` to separate the arguments?

Comment: It highlights the number 31 only, when I deleted the number it puts the cursor between the ) and the ; for NOW();

Comment: Could you try `=Now()` on another cell??

Comment: Result: 5/21/2018 16:52

Comment: Ok... I'm almost sure the problem are the commas. Replace them with `;` on the formula that I published. If the problem persists you have to upload a copy of your file (with just this sheet) so I could have a better look.